# Requiring multiple string conditions in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

```
SELECT stu.First_Name, stu.Last_Name, stu.Phone
FROM Student stu
JOIN Enrollment e
ON stu.Student_Id = e.Student_Id
JOIN Section sec
ON e.Section_Id = sec.Section_Id
JOIN Course c
ON sec.Course_No = c.Course_No
WHERE c.Description = 'Systems Analysis' AND c.Description = 'Project Managment'
```

Hey all, hopefully the last question for today (I'm so sorry).  I was wondering if there is a way to check for multiple string conditions (being an AND, not OR).  When I use just one my joins work alright, but I can't seem to work past using both.  My textbook wants me to solve it with only using the string keywords for the courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR` and filter only the rows having the same number of instances to the the number of filter specified in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  stu.First_Name, 
        stu.Last_Name, 
        stu.Phone
FROM    Student stu
        JOIN Enrollment e
            ON stu.Student_Id = e.Student_Id
        JOIN Section sec
            ON e.Section_Id = sec.Section_Id
        JOIN Course c
            ON sec.Course_No = c.Course_No
WHERE   c.Description IN ('Systems Analysis', 'Project Managment') -- two values
GROUP   BY stu.First_Name, stu.Last_Name, stu.Phone
HAVING  COUNT(*)  = 2 -- rows must have 2 instances
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response John.  I also had Management spelled wrong. Facepalm.  Good to go, you're the bomb.

Comment: Hmm... How do you guarantee there aren't two rows, both with **the same** description? Better: `HAVING MAX(c.Description) <> MIN(c.Description)`.

Comment: @mathguy `COUNT(DISTINCT c.Description) = 2` will work too

Comment: Either way; `COUNT(*)`, though, will not.